# Passing object from dll to exe

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, enterprise-architect

I'm writing EA Addin and AFAIR I have to register `COM`, but that implicate I need `dll`. But I have normal app in `WPF` and I'd like to just separate starting Addin and exe. I want to EA use my `dll` to start my main app, but I don't know how to pass `Repository` object from `dll` to my app, have you got any suggestion? Or even my idea to separate dll and exe is wrong?

Comment: It is certainly possible to have an Add-In start an application which in turn connects to an EA repository, as detailed in my answer. It is unusual to do so, however, but without more information about your specific case it is impossible to tell whether it is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem other, very simple way. I've got two projects in my solution DLL and EXE. When I click on menuItem, DLL execute this:

```
var app = new App();
app.InitializeComponent();
app.Run();
Window1.Repository = _repository; //I know static field is bad, but this is only example
```

And it's work ;)

Answer (score 1):

The EA Add-In has to be a DLL.

If all you want the Add-In to do is start another application, that's simple enough: just make the appropriate system call. Instead of passing the repository to the application, pass `Repository.ConnectionString` and have the application open it using `Repository.OpenFile()`.

Comment: That was my second idea if i can't find nothing else ;) But thanks ;)